# French numerals: the reason/historical background of using "vingt" to form 80 and 90

Tags: nombres

Why in French numerals number "vingt" is being used to form 80 & 90 instead of more convential number formation related with nymber 8 and 9 respectively like in English?

It's somehow reminds me old English monetary system which was too difficult to understand, any connection with this?